# Should I close or give my own answer on questions that have become moot?

Tags: discussion, support

Over time as I've become more familiar with the Stack Exchange way of doing things, I see the value of making sure my questions see resolution. Either that an answer gets accepted, or that the question be closed. People are more inclined to respond to someone who has a higher acceptance rate and all that.

Okay, but it seems to me more than other SE networks I'm a part of, questions I ask here seem to have a more fleeting relevance. I notice with a bunch of questions I ask, that if they go enough time without a suitable answer, then one of two things happen.

One is that some upgrade or change makes the problem magically go away. I find often I don't know exactly what changed, but sometimes things that were problems just go away.

The other is that I end up moving on, away from the problem. So, for example, if I'm using some problematic software, I might just eventually give up on it. I find other software, or another way of doing things, and while the problem technically remains, it's not relevant to me anymore.

This is different, from, say, asking on one of the language based SE networks (Japanese or German or English or whatever )where the language is unlikely to evolve that fast, so a question can wait indefinitely for an answer.

So, in these cases, when life has moved on and I have these old questions around, what should I do with them? Put in an answer and mark it resolved? Flag it to be closed? I don't have enough points on my account to vote to close things on my own.

What's the accepted way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 6):

Unless of course you can give an answer like "This problem was resolved in an update" (or if you feel that's not a satisfactory answer) then it should be closed as "too localized". Keeping it open after you've moved on won't help future users with that issue. I'd be far better to leave a comment saying "I no longer experience this issue" and then having it closed. If someone else has that issue in the future they can open a new question and provide more details as they experience the issue. This has kind of become the accepted practice for questions of this nature.

Comment: So how do you mark the question when you have given up on getting an answer?